# how can create and append an element to document body? (angular)

Tags: angularjs

In a directive i want to create a div and append it to the document. what am i doing wrong?

```
var mover = angular.element('<div></div>');

    mover.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0px',
      bottom: '0px',
      left: '33px',
      width: '50px',
      background: 'blue',
      zIndex: '2'
    });

    $document.append( mover );
```

Comment: Where is the directive?  Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: How about reconsidering the approach? Place the element always in the DOM and compile/show it when needed with a specific className probably to avoid the css in code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you still have to append your element on on another element. Try something like this:

```
var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
body.append(mover)
```

Comment: jQuery + angular? WTF!?

Comment: @brabertaser19 - jQuery comes bundled with jqLite, a stripped down version of jQuery, you can override this with full-fat jQuery by simply including it before angular in your `<script>` declarations.

Comment: For any future readers, @brabertaser19 means Angular comes bundled with jqLite rather than jQuery

Answer (score 45):

Maybe a lighter weight approach would be:

```
angular.element(document.body).append(myElement);
```

Comment: this solution is actually same if we use $rootScope.append(document.body). document.body is the only thing from angular which we can refer to the current document. while if you include jquery before angular then you can use like angular.element('#someelement').

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the angular way! :thumbsup

Answer (score 11):

I think this will be better way to append an element into body

```
var mover = angular.element('<div></div>');

mover.css({
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '0px',
  bottom: '0px',
  left: '33px',
  width: '50px',
  background: 'blue',
  zIndex: '2'
});

var body = angular.element(document).find('body').eq(0);

body.append(mover)
```

Comment: angular.element(document) === $document;

Comment: @thinkwinwin You can use what you like. Both are correct.