# Finding a child of a HTMLCollection by attribute value

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Within a unit test for an angular directive, I want to inspect the DOM that has been compiled:

```
var element = $compile("<div pr-sizeable='...'></div>")($rootScope);
var children = element[0].children;   // HTMLCollection

expect(children.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);  // that's fine
```

Especially, I want to check for the existence of a specific child element having an attribute `pr-swipe-handler='right'`.

I know I could iterate the children and their attributes-collections, but I'm sure there is a more tense solution.

Here's what I tried (refering to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083467/571213) of a similar post):

```
// TypeError: angular.element(...).querySelector is not a function
angular.element(children).querySelector("[pr-swipe-handler='right']")

// TypeError: children.querySelector is not a function
angular.element(children.querySelector("[pr-swipe-handler='right']"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Peter Ashwell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261409/571213) showed me the right direction. Inspecting the HTMLCollection using the querySelector-api is possible only if the elements of the HTMLCollection are part of the actual DOM. Therefore it is necessary to append the compiled elements to it.

Thanks to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22349478/571213) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22349280/571213), it turns out that the compiled element has to be appended to a **concrete** element in the DOM of the browser, such as `body`. `$document` is not enough:

```
  var element = $compile('<div><p></p><div pr-swipe-handler="right"></div></div>')($scope);
  var body = $document.find('body');
  $document.append(element);   // That's not enough.
  //body.append(element);      // That works fine.
  var rightHandler = document.querySelectorAll('[pr-swipe-handler="right"]');
  $scope.info = rightHandler.length + ' element(s) found.';
```

Refer to this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BffflWeaCOeBE5chBQPP?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plunkr that should help you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YRSgbsGCWGujhiOGV97z?p=preview

Code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($compile, $document, $scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var element = $compile('<div><p></p><div pr-swipe-handler="right"></div></div>')($scope);
  console.log(element[0]);
  console.log(element);
  $document.append(element);
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[pr-swipe-handler="right"]'))
});
```

You can not call querySelector on an element, but you can call it on document. You'll need to append the element to document in your tests, but you should be doing that anyway.

Comment: The last line prints "NodeList [  ]" to the console, and also inspecting the DOM in the browser does not reveal any existence of the appended elements. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did the plunkr not work? I didn't mean to include the console.log statements.

Comment: What browser are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Yes, the output is from the plunker. I run it in Firefox. But it's essentially the same in Chrome and IE.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22349478/571213) gave the right hint: if I append the element to a concrete element such as `body`, then it works.

Comment: well yeah, the append line is right there in my code too

Comment: $document.append(element)